# able to run chrome in Android WebView?

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, webview

When you open a page in Android WebView
If you click a link that contains any parameters on that page
Is there a way to run Chrome and show the page in that parameter?

Comment: What if the user doesn't have chrome installed on their Android device?

Comment: @AdamGardner chrome is installed by default

Comment: Yes, but a user can install others and use those and make those the default so chrome is never used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
String urlWithData = yourUrl + "?data=" + theString;
webView.loadUrl(urlWithData);
```

Comment: i wanna use only html and javascript